# IF/THEN formula in excel to compare columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to have two columns equal each other in excel. The first column (AC) has the value "." and the second column (BA) has the value "0". I want something that says if BA=0 then AC is a match to it. I am doing some comparisons and because of this difference the comparisons are not recognizing that  these two are actually a match. There are around 18,000 rows on this so I'm hoping to do an IF/THEN formula rather than change all of the 0s.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: So all you want to find out is whether the `BA` column has a `0` in each cell? I don't see where the `THEN` part would come into play here...

Comment: I am comparing columns so I need it to say something about if BA is 0 and AC is "." then they are the same thing. I just assumed I would need a then in there because that's how you would say it out loud. I'm very new to this stuff.

Comment: Does a comma between then act as the "then" in this place?

Comment: Not quite. See my answer for the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IF` and and `AND` to do this.

**Formula Explanation:**

This is your basic `IF` statement. It performs a logical test, and if that test returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` it will display the appropriate value.

```
=IF(LOGICAL_TEST, VALUE IF TRUE, VALUE IF FALSE)
```

To test two values during the `LOGICAL_TEST` you can use an `AND()`.

```
=IF(AND(LOGICAL_TEST_1, LOGICAL_TEST_2), VALUE IF TRUE, VALUE IF FALSE)
```

If both test are `TRUE`, the `AND` will return `TRUE` to the `IF` statement and display the appropriate value.

**Making it work:**

```
=IF(AND(B2=0,A2="."), "Same", "Not Same")
```

This will compare the cells `A2` and `B2`, and if they are both `.` and `0` will print `Same`. Otherwise it will print `Not Same`.

Comment: @Jourdain Please remember to mark Answers that solve your problem with a Tick. This ensures that anyone else that finds this question knows the answer works.